# View-based NSTableView in Swift does not show content

Tags: swift, nstableview

I'm trying to show a very basic data structure in a view-based NSTableView. After hours of searching, I finally got to a point where most of the table is set up. The number of rows is correct, I know the `func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int)` method is executed for all cells because it prints the correct data in the console. Unfortunately, the table shows with the default value instead of the `String`s from my data array.

[image: The table view doesn't display the correct data]

Here's the code:

ViewController.swift

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: NSTableView!
    var files = [FilesListData]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setupSampleFiles()
    }
    override func viewDidAppear() {
        super.viewDidAppear()
    }

    func setupSampleFiles() {
        let file1 = FilesListData(file: "test.mp3", title: "test")
        let file2 = FilesListData(file: "test2.mp3", title: "test 2")

        self.files = [file1, file2]
    }
}

extension ViewController: NSTableViewDataSource {  
    func numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return self.files.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> AnyObject? {
        let cellView: NSTableCellView = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier((tableColumn!.identifier), owner: self) as! NSTableCellView

        let fileData = self.files[row]
        if tableColumn!.identifier == "fileCol" {
            cellView.textField!.stringValue = fileData.file
        } else if tableColumn!.identifier == "titleCol" {
            cellView.textField!.stringValue = fileData.title
        } else {
            cellView.textField!.stringValue = "N/A"
        }
        return cellView
    }
}

extension ViewController: NSTableViewDelegate {
}
```

FilesListData.swift

```
import Foundation

class FilesListData: NSObject {
    var file: String
    var title: String

    override init() {
        self.file = String()
        self.title = String()
    }

    init(file: String, title: String) {
        self.file = file
        self.title = title
    }
}
```

A few more notes: in the storyboard, I did create an outlet for `dataSource` and `delegate` to the View Controller. The identifiers of my first 2 columns are set to "fileCol" and "titleCol". The project compiles and runs without any error or warning. Below are a few screenshots of my storyboard.

[image: Objects tree]

[image: Identifier for the first column]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've mixed up two different methods. The **data source** method `tableView(_:objectValueForTableColumn:row:)` is for returning a data object, not a cell view. The **delegate** method `tableView(_:viewForTableColumn:row:)` is for returning a cell view, possibly configured with the data appropriate for the column and row.

So, you might rewrite the former as:

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> AnyObject? {
    let fileData = self.files[row]
    if tableColumn!.identifier == "fileCol" {
        return fileData.file
    } else if tableColumn!.identifier == "titleCol" {
        return fileData.title
    }

    return "N/A"
}
```

Note that it doesn't attempt to create or return a view.

That's the first step. The table view will take the object value that you've returned from that method and assign it to the `objectValue` property of the `NSTableCellView` that you're using as your cell view. However, by itself, that doesn't do anything.

There are a few different approaches to take to get that object value to actually show up in your cell views:

- Instead of using `NSTableCellView`s, each containing a text field, as your cell views, use a text field itself. Since `NSTextField` also has an `objectValue` property (inherited from `NSControl`), the table view can set the object value on that and your content shows up. The disadvantage is that your cell views are just a single view. If you want to get fancy with multiple views in each cell, you can't use this approach.
- Keep using `NSTableCellView`s as your cell views, as you're doing now. Bind the text field's Value binding to the containing `NSTableCellView` with the key path `objectValue`. That way, when the table sets the `objectValue` of the `NSTableCellView`, it's automatically propagated to the text field.
- Implement `tableView(_:viewForTableColumn:row:)` to configure the cell view by directly setting the value of the text field's properties. Basically, this would look like the body of what you had implemented for `tableView(_:objectValueForTableColumn:row:)`. This effectively makes your implementation of `tableView(_:objectValueForTableColumn:row:)` redundant. You're required to implement it and the table view will call it and use the result to set the `objectValue` of the cell views, but that will have no effect on the text fields within the cell views.
- Use a custom subclass of `NSTableCellView` which adds a `didSet` property observer to the `objectValue` property. That can forward the new value to the subviews as appropriate.

Personally, I use the bindings approach.

Also, you should consider returning the whole `fileData` object, rather than the value of one of its properties, from `tableView(_:objectValueForTableColumn:row:)`. So, `tableView(_:objectValueForTableColumn:row:)` will not be sensitive to the column, only the row. The `objectValue` of each `NSTableCellView` will be the corresponding `FilesListData` instance.

Then, the bindings of text fields to their enclosing cell view would be adjusted to select the appropriate property of the `FilesListData`. For example, the text field in one column would be bound to its enclosing `NSTableCellView` with a key path of `objectValue.file`. In the other column, it would use a key path of `objectValue.title`.

This is especially useful if your cell views eventually get more complex with multiple views in them. Each view has access to any of the properties of the `FilesListData` object. With your current approach of returning just a single property as the cell's object value, then the views are stuck working with just that one value.

Comment: Hello Ken and thank you for the thorough answer. I would like to keep `NSTableCellView`s since as you mentioned, I will be able to expand on the complexity of the table later. I was able to successfully display data by implementing `tableView(_:viewForTableColumn:row:)`. However, the binding method seems very interesting but I don't know how to implement this. The "Value" that you mention would be the `delegate` outlet? N.B.: One thing I didn't mention is that my `NSTableCellView`'s `textField` has an outlet to its child `NSTextField`.

Comment: The easiest way to set up the binding is in IB. With the text field selected, choose View > Utilities > Show Bindings Inspector. Toggle open the Value binding. For the Bind To pop-up, select the table cell view. For Model Key Path enter `objectValue.file` or something like that. (Xcode will show an exclamation point icon because it can't verify that the key path is valid, but you can ignore that. It's the nature of a system as dynamic as this that it can't know what type `objectValue` will be.)